# How to create Inbox like floating action button in Android with Speed dial animation

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to create a **floating action button** that will animate to show inner speed dial buttons like **Inbox android app** developed by Google.

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the expected output by using **Floating Action Button Speed Dial** library.

The library is available on Jcenter so no additonal repository is required.

**Step 1:** Add the following dependency

```
implementation "com.leinardi.android:speed-dial:2.0.0"
```

**Step 2:** Add the `SpeedDialView` to your layout:

```
<com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
    android:id="@+id/speedDial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:sdMainFabClosedSrc="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
```

**Step 3:** Add the items to the `SpeedDialView`:

```
SpeedDialView speedDialView = findViewById(R.id.speedDial);
speedDialView.addActionItem(
    new SpeedDialActionItem.Builder(R.id.fab_link, R.drawable.ic_link_white_24dp)
            .create());
```

**Step 4:** Add the click listeners:

```
speedDialView.setOnActionSelectedListener(new SpeedDialView.OnActionSelectedListener() {
@Override
public boolean onActionSelected(SpeedDialActionItem speedDialActionItem) {
    switch (speedDialActionItem.getId()) {
        case R.id.fab_link:
            showToast("Link action clicked!");
            return false; // true to keep the Speed Dial open
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
});
```

**Source:** https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial

Comment: What is "fab_link" here..?

Answer (score 3):

The [FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial) is the best library i have found that suits your requirements. 
 
It's quite flexible and you can find that the repository's [Main Sample](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/leinardi/android/speeddial/sample/MainActivity.java) implementing a lot of possible use cases such as add/remove button from the floating menu, change the color of labels and button background etc. 
 
The only drawback I've found in the meantime is that you have to add your buttons  programmatically and not in the xml layout file. 
 
Anyway, the first answer is good but he missed a small detail. When you create a button to add to your SpeedDialView:

```
speedDialView.addActionItem(
new SpeedDialActionItem.Builder(R.id.fab_link, R.drawable.ic_link_white_24dp)
        .create());
```

The **R.id.fab_link** is the id of the new ActionItem (floating button) so you can reference it afterwards in the onClickListener of the speedDialView:

```
speedDialView.setOnActionSelectedListener(new SpeedDialView.OnActionSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onActionSelected(SpeedDialActionItem actionItem) {
                switch (actionItem.getId()) {
                    case R.id.fab_add:
                        // do something
                        break;
                    case R.id.fab_link:
                        // do something else
                        break;
                }
                return true; // To keep the Speed Dial open
            }
        });
```

It's just an **@IdRes**, an integer that is expected to be an id resource reference. 
So you can do like they did in the official sample [here](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/values/ids.xml), and create a resource file containing items with type *id*. 
 
I hope you find this answer helpful.